# change the value of a word custom field with vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

i use VBA to read data from an excel file and insert it into an word document.
Now i am stuck on how i can change the value of an "custom word field".
I add a field in the word document in th word menu (menu->info->properties->advanced properties->custom).
Here is an Guide how i added the custom fields: 
[click me](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/automate-microsoft-word-forms-with-custom-fields/)

my field has the name "w_ean".

I tried something like this, but i always get a runtime error 13..

```
Function FnOpeneWordDoc()

    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc


    ' Word Objekt erstellen
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    ' Word Dokument öffnen
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("myFile.docx")
    ' Word sichtbar machen!
    objWord.Visible = True

    objDoc.Fields("w_ean").Result = "123"
End Function
```

Comment: You might want to research a bit farther on the topic of what can be used as a "data target" in a Word document: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903311/exporting-data-from-excel-to-word-data-targets-placeholders/49904015#49904015

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you may have a `DocProperty` field in your document you do not set its value directly. Instead you set the value of the `CustomProperty` that you created and to which the field refers.

```
objDoc.CustomProperties("w_ean").Value = "123"
```

After you have set the value of the property you will need to update the fields in your document so that the correct value is displayed.