# Why does the values in cells (Excel) aren't replacing the variables in the Words files?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, generator

I made an excel file that the user should fill in one column details, after he finishes he is clicking on a button that generate three Word files.
At the Excel I named the cells where the details of the user were written. at the word files I placed the variables (the names of the cells) where I wanted.
every things is working well beside the replacment between the details that the user enters to the variables in the words files.

```
Sub createPDF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim theString As String
Dim TemplatePath As String
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim Pscope As String
'ws.Activate
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
TemplatePath = xWb.Path
objWord.Visible = True

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.doc*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myfile = Dir(TemplatePath + "\Template" & "\" & myExtension)

'Loop through each word file in folder
Do While myfile <> ""
objWord.Documents.Open TemplatePath + "\Template" & "\" & myfile 'TemplatePath + "\ProposalTemplate.dotm" ' change as required



With objWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Find

.Text = "company_ename"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("company_ename").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


.Text = "owner_fname1"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_fname1").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_pname1"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_pname1").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_fullname1"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_fullname1").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_id1"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_id1").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_allotted1"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_allotted1").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


For i = 2 To 4
.Text = "owner_fname" & CStr(i)
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_fname" & CStr(i)).Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_pname" & CStr(i)
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_pname" & CStr(i)).Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_fullname" & CStr(i)
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_fullname" & CStr(i)).Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_id" & CStr(i)
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_id" & CStr(i)).Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "owner_allotted" & CStr(i)
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("owner_allotted" & CStr(i)).Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


Next i

.Text = "house"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("house").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "director_pname1"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("director_pname1").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

.Text = "director_fname1"
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = True
.replacement.Text = ws.Range("director_fname1").Value
.wrap = wdfindcontinue
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


End With

Dim TheFileName As String
        TheFileName = TemplatePath + "\Output\" + ws.Range("company_ename").Value + "_" + Replace(myfile, "docx", "") + ".docx"

        '(SaveAs is for Office 2003 and earlier - deprecated)
        objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs TheFileName
            'replaces existing .doc iff exists


        ' Close Documents and Quit Word
        objWord.ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=False
       ' objWord.ActiveDocument.Close 'close .DOCx
 myfile = Dir
Loop
Set objWord = Nothing

MsgBox "Generation Complete!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: We need more information. Please provide a small sample of the Excel data and the Word document. Also, given the description of what you want to do I highly recommend reading up on BOOKMARKS and CONTENTCONTROLS as "data targets", rather than relying on Find/Replace. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903311/exporting-data-from-excel-to-word-data-targets-placeholders/49904015#49904015

Comment: Try use some `Debug.Print` statements to determine where things could be going wrong.

Comment: You might have issues if some of the items you're replacing are substrings of other items: I would place tags more like "{owner_fname}"

Comment: Consider rephrasing the title of the question, the title is pretty unclear to me. Also, the more precise and on point the example you provide, the more likely you are to get a constructive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of repeated code which should be in a separate sub.

For example:

```
Sub createPDF()

    Dim objWord As Object, doc As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim theString As String
    Dim TheFileName As String, nm, i As Long
    Dim TemplatePath As String, myExtension, myfile
    Dim Pscope As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    TemplatePath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

    myExtension = "*.doc*"
    myfile = Dir(TemplatePath + "\Template" & "\" & myExtension)

    Do While myfile <> ""
        Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(TemplatePath + "\Template" & "\" & myfile)
        For Each nm In Array("company_ename", "owner_fname1", "owner_pname1", _
                             "owner_fullname1", "owner_id1", "owner_allotted1", _
                             "house", "director_pname1", "director_fname1")
            DoReplace doc, ws, nm
        Next nm

        For i = 2 To 4
            For Each nm In Array("owner_fname", "owner_pname", "owner_fullname", _
                                    "owner_id", "owner_allotted")
                DoReplace doc, ws, nm & CStr(i)
            Next nm
        Next i

        TheFileName = TemplatePath & "\Output\" & ws.Range("company_ename").Value & _
                      "_" & Replace(myfile, "docx", "") & ".docx"

        doc.SaveAs TheFileName
        doc.Close savechanges:=False

        myfile = Dir
    Loop
    Set objWord = Nothing

    MsgBox "Generation Complete!"

End Sub

Sub DoReplace(doc As Object, ws As Worksheet, txt)
    With doc.Content.Find
        .Text = "{" & txt & "}" 'in the Word doc the tag is enclosed in{}
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .replacement.Text = ws.Range(txt).Value
        .wrap = 1 'wdfindcontinue
        .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```